# Angular and Ionic 2 : Showing 2 columns per row with NgFor and a conditional display

Tags: angular, ionic-framework, ionic2

What I'm trying to do is to show a 2 columns per row in an ionic 2 app, and when a user enters some text in search box, for example typing a a text that only exists on the second row, the first one disappears (which actually happens now, but keeps the second column on the right and not getting it in the place of the hidden one).

Here is the code I'm using now which is not getting my columns in same row :

```
<ion-grid>
    <div [ngSwitch]="top">
      <div *ngSwitchCase="'resto'">
        <ion-row responsive-sm wrap *ngFor="let data of topRestaurants | ArrayObject ">
          <ion-col col-6 *ngIf="data.value['title'].toLowerCase().includes(textFilter)">
            <ion-card>
                <ion-col col-12 no-margin no-padding><img src="{{data.value['logo']}}"/></ion-col>
                <ion-col col-12 no-margin no-padding>
                  <ion-card-content>
                    <ion-card-title>
                      {{data.value['title']}} <ion-badge item-end>{{(data.value['distance']) | number:'1.2-2'}} km</ion-badge>
                    </ion-card-title>
                    <p>
                      <small><rating [score]="data.value['overall_rating']" [max]="5"></rating> ({{data.value['reviews_count']}}) Avis</small>
                    </p>
                  </ion-card-content>
                </ion-col>
            </ion-card>
          </ion-col>
        </ion-row>
      </div>
```

When I make the ion-col style like following : display : inline-block, width:50%, it makes it works almost fine, but makes the block keeps his place (the 50%) even when ngIf is false (because the row still exists on the DOM, and we remove the col instead :/ )

[image]

Comment: Then I guess you have to read my whole question, as in some part as the title mention it, there is an If holding a part of the issue :)

Comment: Yeah :) Maybe i dont understand, but dont you want the items always be in rows with two columns? If you have the *ngFor on the ion-col you will have one row, but n columns. But because as soon as the column "width count" exceeds 12 it will break to a new line. The way you have it now you keep ion-cols from moving vertically.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can move the `*ngFor` from the `<ion-row>` to the `<ion-col>`. The way you have it now prevents the `<ion-col>`s from ever moving vertically because they will stay in their rows. If you move the `*ngFor` you will only have one `<ion-row>` with n `<ion-col>`s. When you have a column width of 6 (`col-6`) you will only have two columns on a row anyway, because when the column width exceeds 12 it will break to a new row. When one of your items gets removed because of the `*ngIf` the layout will adjust itself.

One problem that will come out of moving the `*ngFor`-statement is that you will have to move the `*ngIf`, because you can not have multiple structural-directives (*ngIf, *ngFor) on a host element ([structural directive docs](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/structural-directives.html#!#one-per-element)).

Comment: That is the problem. The ng if when trigered wont remove the col but only the card and thus will leave a white space instead of leaving its place to the next col

Comment: Great! So then you know what you need to do! :)

Comment: To be franc no, that was the purpose of the questions :D

Comment: To be franc right back at you, :) that was not obvious. You could use a [pipe](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/pipes.html) to filter the array.

Comment: So what exactly is your question? How to implement the pipe?

Answer (score 0):

Move the *ngFor to your columns, and manipulate the actual array rather then just throwing an *ngIf on it to prevent certain 'data' from showing.

I also dont think its efficient to bind a filter to an ngIf like youre doing.